# I can not get the result right

Tags: integration, trigonometry, stochastic-processes

**Intro**

---

I am studying the mean from a random process $x(t)$ where $\theta$ is a random variable with pdf = $1/2\pi$

$x(t) = \cos(\omega t + \theta);$

and I go as this:

$E\{x(t)\} = E\{\cos(\omega t + \theta)\}$ which is $\int_{-A}^{A} \cos(\omega t + \theta) * 1/2\pi\, d\theta.$

So far, so good.

---

**The problem** is after doing the integration I end up with this:

---

$\sin(\omega t + \theta)$ where $\theta$ [-A, A] where A must be [A < $\pi$]

and I can not get to the correct result of:

$2 \cos[t \omega] \sin[A].$

---

(*The result is from doing the integration, the $1/2\pi$ is outside the integration waiting*)

My attempt was to use this Euler equation:

$\sin(a + b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\cos(b)$

---

**The Question**

Could you please tell me how to get to that result or what I am missing or need to know?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that 

$$
\mathbb{E}[x] = \int{\rm d}x~ x f_X(x)
$$

where $f_X$ is the pdf of $x$, but you are using $f_\theta = (2\pi)^{-1}$ instead. And those are very different things

Comment: Actually i solved it.  I forgot Eulers equation of $\sin(a) - sen(b) = 2cos((a+b)/2)sin((a-b)/2); I've been studying the whole day (i enjoy studying) so i did a break to refresh and came up with the right solution afterwards.